# Push sub-array to a specific key in an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach, key

I'm sure this is easy to do, I'm just new to this level of PHP programming. Also, please forgive my terminology, I don't know the official names for things, so let me know if something's not clear.

Alright, so I'm building a calendar in PHP, and I've got everything almost working, except I can only display one event per day. I realized this is because I'm storing the event data as sub-keys for a specific key in an array.

Essentially I'm creating each day in the calendar as key in the array. For example:

```
$events["1"] = "first day of the month";
$events["2"] = "second day of the month";
$events["3"] = "third day of the month";
...
```

And then inside of each of those, I'm doing something like this:

```
$events["1"]["title"] = "title for the event on the first day of the month";
$events["1"]["time"]  = "time for the event on the first day of the month";
$events["2"]["title"] = "title for the event on the second day of the month";
$events["2"]["time"]  = "time for the event on the second day of the month";
...
```

This setup means I can only store one event per day. If I where to try to set up multiple events, each subsequent event would overwrite the values from the previous.

So what I want to do is set up each event as an array within that key. For example:

```
$events["1"][0] = array("title" => "first title for the event on the first day of the month", "time" => "first time for the event on the first day of the month");
$events["1"][1] = array("title" => "second title for the event on the first day of the month", "time" => "second time for the event on the first day of the month");
```

I could use `array_push()` to add each event, but I'm not sure how to do that for an array with keys.

Finally, once I have this all stored properly, I need to output each event somehow, so how would I cycle through each sub-array of each day? Right now I'm just doing:

```
foreach ($events as $event) {
    if ($event["title"] != "") {
        echo "<strong>" . $event["title"] . "</strong>";
    }
}
```

I imagine I would need a `foreach` inside the `foreach`, but I'm not quite sure how to set that up.

Thanks for the help. Again, I'm sure this is simple to figure out, I'm just not much of a programmer.

PS: This is all being built for a WordPress site, if that makes a difference. I know there's http://wordpress.stackexchange.com, but I think because this is more general programming questions than anything specific to WordPress that this it the more appropriate site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use text keys, you are better off doing something like:

```
$events["1"]["title"] = "title for the event on the first day of the month";
$events["1"]["time"]  = "time for the event on the first day of the month";
$events["1"]["events"] = array();
```

so that $events[n]['events'] is an array of all of the events on that day.

You don't need array_push. You can add an event by:

```
$events["1"]["events"][] = new event
```

Then you would display the events by:

```
foreach ($events as $event) {
    if ($event["title"] != "") {
        echo "<strong>" . $event["title"] . "</strong>";
    }
    foreach ($event['events'] as $evt) {
        // display the event as you want
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, I'll give it a shot and report back :)